# Marking the location of known raster values within certain polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, extract, con

I have a raster dataset of elevation values, and a feature dataset of polygons that delineate certain objects within the raster dataset. I've used Zonal Statistics to create tables of min, max, percentiles, and so forth for each of the object polygons. However, I want to know *where* each of these values (min, max, 90th percentile, etc.) are within each object polygon, ideally by marking each value with a point. I also would like to repeat this process for many object polygons, so I've been trying to make a modelbuilder model to somewhat automate it. I've made some progress, but both the "Con" and "Extract by Attributes" tools give "Error 1010674: The cell size *x* is too small for the specified raster extent", which torpedoed the plan I had.

Any advice? I'm having a harder time than I expected with this.

Comment: This should be quite easy to do with modelbuilder so that is a good approach, Look at the help file for each tool that is giving you this problem and look at the _environments_ it honours. Cell size will be one of them, ensure that it set to the cell size of your DEM. Or set cell size for the model environment and they should inherit that.

Comment: Yeah, the tool environment seems to have been the issue for Error 1010674, so thank you very much for that advice. It's sadly not all working yet - still trying to get the SQL expression to work well and properly extract the desired raster cells - but it's progress.